# Bash delete files from path that contain space

Tags: linux, bash, macos

```
#!/bin/bash

files_path="/Volumes/HDD/Bogdan Data/"

rm -r "$files_path/files/*"
```

I'm getting an error that path cannot be found, probably due to the space character in the folder name. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$files_path` needs to be quoted, but the `*` glob must not be.

```
rm -r "$files_path"/files/*
```